# Issue in reading values from Dictionary in case of functionapp hosted on Azure environment

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

I have the following function app setup on Azure environment. I tried to follow the inputs from the link and extended it

https://mitra.computa.asia/articles/msdn-smart-image-re-sizing-azure-functions-and-cognitive-services

Here I am trying to generate two different sized thumbnail images whenever any image is uploaded to the container.

I have one input: myBlob and two different outputs added in this case: outputBlobsm, outputBlobmd under the Integrate section.

**Function App Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public static void Run(Stream myBlob,string blobname, string blobextension, Stream outputBlobsm,Stream outputBlobmd, TraceWriter log)
{
    bool smartCropping = true;

    log.Info($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{blobname} \n Extension: {blobextension} extension");

    var sizesm = imageDimensionsTable[ImageSize.Small];
    log.Info($"C# Blob \n Sizesm:{sizesm}");
    log.Info($"C# Blob \n width:{sizesm.item1} \n height: {sizesm.item2}");
    ResizeImage(sizesm.item1, sizesm.item2,smartCropping,myBlob, outputBlobsm);

    var sizemd = imageDimensionsTable[ImageSize.Medium];
    log.Info($"C# Blob \n width:{sizemd.item1} \n height: {sizemd.item2}");
    ResizeImage(sizemd.item1, sizemd.item2,smartCropping,myBlob, outputBlobmd);
}

public void ResizeImage(int width, int height, bool smartCropping,Stream myBlob, Stream outputBlob)
{    
    string _apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    string _apiUrlBase = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/generateThumbnail";
  using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_apiUrlBase);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", _apiKey);
        using (HttpContent content = new StreamContent(myBlob))
        {
            //get response
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            var uri = $"{_apiUrlBase}?width={width}&height={height}&smartCropping={smartCropping.ToString()}";
            var response = httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;
            var responseBytes = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;

            //write to output thumb
            outputBlob.Write(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);
        }
    }
}

public enum ImageSize { ExtraSmall, Small, Medium }

private static Dictionary<ImageSize, (int, int)> imageDimensionsTable = new Dictionary<ImageSize, (int, int)>() {
    { ImageSize.ExtraSmall, (320, 200) },
    { ImageSize.Small,      (640, 400) },
    { ImageSize.Medium,     (800, 600) }
};
```

On compiling the code I am getting the below error:

```
[Error] run.csx(16,41): error CS1061: '(int, int)' does not contain a definition for 'item1' and no extension method 'item1' accepting a first argument of type '(int, int)' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Since it looks like a pure C# syntactic issue, I suggest reproducing the same in a plain Console app, and leaving Functions out of the equations in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# is case sensitive. The new tuples if you haven't specified names should be Item1, Item2....

[See examples here under "Tuples"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/)

Note that you can also specify names for those ints in the declaration:

```
 private static Dictionary<ImageSize, (int Width, int Height)> imageDimensionsTable
```

which makes

```
ResizeImage(sizesm.Width, sizesm.Height,smartCropping,myBlob, outputBlobsm);
```

much more readable

Oh... and you'll might need to make `ResizeImage` static

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your solution helped me to fix the issue :)